# Loop through cells range against worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with so many sheets. I have a list of sheet names written somewhere in a sheet. I need to write a function to protect only those sheets which are not in this list.

I think i am stuck at a line of code. Could you help me.

```
Public Function Test()
On Error GoTo Test_Err

Dim wks, xSheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set wks = Worksheets("HideTabs")

With wks
Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each Cell In myRange
For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If xSheet.Name = Cell.Value Then
' Do Something
Exit For
Else
' Do Something else
End If

Next xSheet
Next Cell

Exit Function
Test_Err:
      MsgBox "The Error Happened on (Test Function) Line : " & Erl & vbNewLine & _
           "Error Message : " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
           "Error Number : " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           sMsg, vbCritical, sTitle

End Function
```

Comment: So your question is, *how do I protect / unprotect a worksheet*? I believe this is possibly answered 1000+ times on this site, did you try a quick search?

Comment: Look at this ya amr Ali https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect.aspx

Comment: @ Mat's Mug. No, i  wrote this function as an example. My issue was with `For Each - Next` statement since i have 2 loops inside each other and i can not fix it well.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to make your question clearer. "Stuck at a line of code" is kinda vague, and having nested loops isn't an issue all by itself - please describe the problem you are having, help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to write a function to loop through all workbook sheets and compare it against a defined list in cells range then do some actions.

```
Public Function Test()

Dim wks, xlWSH As Worksheet
Dim myRange, Cell As Range
Dim ProtectIt As Boolean

'Refer to sheet name where you save your sheet names list
Set wks = Worksheets("SheetName")
With wks
'Refer to first cell where your sheet names list starts. Here is "A1"
Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each xlWSH In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

For Each Cell In myRange
'If sheet name is in your list then set DoIt to False
If xlWSH.Name = Cell.Value Then
DoIt = False
Exit For
Else
DoIt = True
End If
Next Cell

If DoIt = True Then
With xlWSH
'Do Some Actions With Sheet
End With
End If

Next xlWSH

End Function
```